# Determinar DateTime para cada día de la semana con PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Tal vez el título no sea el mejor para explicar lo que quiero hacer, pero no se me ocurrió otra forma de expresarlo.

El asunto es el siguiente:
Tengo que desarrollar un pequeño sistema en PHP para gestionar eventos que se realizan cada día de la semana en horarios específicos TODAS las semanas. Ejemplo, los lunes hay dos eventos, uno a las 14 y otro a las 19 horas, pero necesito hacer que el mismo código funcione para todos los lunes y no andar reprogramando las fechas cada semana.

Les muestro lo que armé hasta ahora:

```
$zonaHoraria = "America/Sao_Paulo";
$horaActual = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($zonaHoraria));

$event1Test = new DateTime();
$event1Test->setDate(monday);
$event1Test->setTime(14,00,00);
$event1TestAnuncio = strtotime ('-30 minute', strtotime($event1Test));

if ($horaActual = $event1TestAnuncio)  {
  echo 'El evento 1 comenzará en 30 minutos.';
}
elseif ($horaActual = $event1Test) {
  echo 'El evento 1 ha comenzado.';
}
else {
  echo 'No hay eventos.';
}

$event2Test = new DateTime();
$event2Test->setDate(monday);
$event2Test->setTime(19,00,00);
$event2TestAnuncio = strtotime ('-30 minute', strtotime($event2Test));

if ($horaActual = $event2TestAnuncio )  {
  echo 'El evento 2 comenzará en 30 minutos.';
}
elseif ($horaActual = $event2Test) {
  echo 'El evento 2 ha comenzado.';
}
else {
  echo 'No hay eventos.';
}
```

Con cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme estaría súper agradecido.

Comment: Tube un problema parecido al tuyo hace unos días. En este caso es javascript. Usando la funcion getTime() puedes obtener un número (en ms), el cuál equivale a tu fecha a partir del 01/01/1970. Lo que puedes hacer es cada vez que sea el evento del Lunes, sumarle a este número 7dias(en ms) y volver a pasarlo a fecha (en mi caso con el setTime()) y ya obtienes el siguiente lunes. Todos estos valores lo podrías guardar en un Array de 2x7 (2 eventos x 7 dias) e ir accediendo cuando toque.

Comment: No queda claro lo que deseas lograr

Comment: @Aprendiz quiere lanzar un "evento" cada día de las semanas a las mismas horas, sin tener que preocuparse de que fecha es, el siguiente lunes.

Comment: A mi tampoco queda claro cual es el resultado al que quieres llegar. ¿que se muestre un evento todos los lunes a determinada hora? Con DateTime puedes obtener el día de la semana, ¿por qué no utilizarlo para saber que día es?

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas. Voy a investigar lo que dice Xerif y ver si puedo validar el día con el DateTime y un variable que contenga el día en string y así lograr que solo haga el anuncio cumpliendo esa validación. Si a alguien se le ocurre alguna otra forma más práctica de lograrlo los leeré atentamente, nuevamente gracias.